# Minecraft ComputerCraft error?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

i'm trying to make what i understand to be a very basic line of code. for frame of reference i am familiar with basic java, but have very little skill. i am using the [StargateTech 2 mod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4brIG.jpg)  the code is:

```
rednet.open("front") -- the wireless modem is attached to the front of the computer
id,message = rednet.receive(100) -- receive message, or wait 100 seconds
if message == "dial" then
rednet.send(3,"Dialling DHD...") -- 3 is the ID of the wireless pocket computer
bus = peripheral.wrap("bottom") -- the peripheral chosen is the bottom face
bus.sendPacket("FFFF", "action: dial", "address: Dehsetcro Erpurrum Etrush") -- error line
end -- ends the 'if' function, 'else' not necessary
rednet.close("front") -- disconnects from the wireless modem
```

the issue is "rednet:6: attempt to index ? (a nil value)", but i believe i've typed it correctly. as i understand it, the issue is with the format. any advice?
Edit: the programming language is Lua

Comment: This sounds like a fancy NullPointerException. Maybe you can try `if message == null` (without quotation marks) before it to test for a missing response? I don't know which programming language this is based on (it's not Java, because Java doesn't have "then" and "end"), so it might also be called "NULL", "Null", "nil" or something else. It might also be an empty string, in which case you could compare with `""`, but that shouldn't throw an error. You can also try it once with `message = "test"` and once with `message = "dial"` above the condition to see what happens.

Comment: For people who know this mod it might be obvious, but you should also mention where you are entering this text.

Comment: i'm entering the text in a normal ComputerCraft computer, the message it waits to receive comes from a wireless pocket computer. the error line and the one above it are all that's needed if i'm running it straight from the computer, so it would probably be easier if i tell it to execute upon receiving the text

Comment: knowing my luck, there's probably nothing wrong with it and it's just a power supply problem

Comment: Always test such things in a Creative world if you're unsure. But if you get an error message, it should be a problem with the program, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i removed the IF function and waited for the power supply to max out, all issues solved. i was right -- it was simply a power supply issue.